# How to send ifconfig from a Linux application?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am writing a program on Linux. I would like to read ifconfig and screen on the tabwidged. I have no idea how I can do that.

I found [this example](http://www.codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/QTabWidgetSetTabButton.php#.U2SQY_l_u31). I would like to upgrade this.

---

I have many errors

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:7:19: error: variable ‘QApplication app’ has initializer but incomplete type
/usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qtabwidget.h:167:14: error: ‘QTabBar* QTabWidget::tabBar() const’ is protected
main.cpp:21:14: error: within this context
main.cpp:21:15: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct QTabBar’
/usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qtabwidget.h:56:7: error: forward declaration of ‘struct QTabBar’
main.cpp:21:33: error: incomplete type ‘QTabBar’ used in nested name specifier
main.cpp:21:63: error: ‘button3’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:23:1: error: ‘myprocess’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:25:11: error: ‘ps’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:26:9: error: ‘myTabWidget’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

        QApplication app(argc, argv);
        QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow();  

        window->setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("MainWindow"));
        window->resize(480, 480);
        QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget(window);
        QTabWidget *tabs = new QTabWidget(centralWidget);

        tabs->setFixedSize(440, 440);
        tabs->addTab(new QWidget(),"TAB 1");  
        tabs->addTab(new QWidget(),"TAB 2");
        tabs->addTab(new QWidget(),"TAB 3");

tabs->tabBar()->setTabButton(2, QTabBar::LeftSide,((QWidget*)(button3)));
QProcess myProcess;
myprocess.start("ifconfig");
if (myProcess.waitForStarted(-1)) {

    while(ps.waitForReadyRead(-1)) {
        myTabWidget.setText(1, myprocess.readAllStandardOutput());
    }
}
window->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);


        window->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
        window->show();

        return app.exec();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [QProcess](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QProcess.html) and/or [QtNetwork](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtnetwork-index.html) to get this information into your tab widget.

```
...
tabs->tabBar()->setTabButton(2, QTabBar::LeftSide,((QWidget*)(button3)));
QProcess myProcess;
myprocess.start("ifconfig");
if (myProcess.waitForStarted(-1)) {
    while(ps.waitForReadyRead(-1)) {
        myTabWidget.setText(your_index, myprocess.readAllStandardOutput());
    }
}
window->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
...
```

That being said, you could look into QtNetwork to be more portable as "ifconfig" will not work on Windows, etc. You would need to change that to ipconfig and so on.

To be fair, even on Linux, you should look into the "ip" command instead of the old and hardly maintained "ifconfig".

Therefore, you would be looking for [QNetworkInterface](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkinterface.html) and [QHostAddress](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qhostaddress.html) with a proper cross-platform solution. Here is a short example:

```
foreach(const QNetworkInterface &interface, QNetworkInterface::allInterfaces())
    qDebug() << interface.hardwareAddress();

foreach(const QHostAdress &address, QNetworkInterface::allAddresses())
    qDebug() << address.toString();
```

Answer (score -1):

If all you're looking for is the IP address, you might want to use `gethostbyname()` instead of calling an external program (like ifconfig on Linux, or ipconfig on Windows).

If you want additional information (besides IP addresses), you might also want to consider reading from /proc/net (Linux only):

- http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/linux/2000/11/16/LinuxAdmin.html

Comment: Please do not propose a linux specific solution if you wish diverge from the original question, and well, reading from /proc/net is even worse.